# Hover over an image in one column to make text appear in a different column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Apologies as I know this question has been asked in various different forms, but I can't find an answer to my exact problem - at least not one that I understand!

I'm very new to programming, and am currently building myself a webpage for my wedding cake business to try and familiarise myself with HTML, CSS and a bit of JavaScript and JQuery. I have a list of thumbnail images in one column, which I added "onmouseover" to so that when hovered over (in addition to a css transition) they display a large version of themselves in a central column. I want to also display information about each cake in a third column to the right hand side of the main image but I have no idea how to go about doing this!

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<ul class="cake-thumbs">
    <li>
        <figure class="cake-img">
            <img onmouseover="getElementById('preview').src=this.src" id="img10" src="Resources/img/10.jpg" alt="Pastel Pink Placard and Pearls">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure class="cake-img">
            <img onmouseover="getElementById('preview').src=this.src" id="img11" src="Resources/img/11.jpg" alt="Naked Wedding Cake with fresh fruit">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure class="cake-img">
            <img onmouseover="getElementById('preview').src=this.src" id="img12" src="Resources/img/12.jpg" alt="Gold Damask and Pearls">
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
        <img id="preview" src="Resources/img/1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <p id="info">Price and servings here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Missing `document.` at `getElementById()`, `document.getElementById()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've removed the mouse over events that were directly attached to the elements, and created a child div with a class "info" that will get copied to the third column when hovered.  I attached an attribute "data-preview" to each img that contains the full sized image to place in the preview column.

I've also bound the event to click in addition to the mouseenter so that when mobile users visit your site, they can click the image (very few mobiles support mouse events).

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter click','.cake-img',function(){
  $('#preview').attr('src',$('img',this).data('preview')); // Copy source to preview
  $('#info').html($('.info',this).html()); // Copy text
});
```

```css
body{padding-top: 75px} /* Look pretty in stack overflow full screen */
.cake-thumbs figure { display: inline-block }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
<ul class="cake-thumbs">
    <li>
        <figure class="cake-img">
            <img id="img10" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100/00ffff?text=Thumbnail" alt="Pastel Pink Placard and Pearls" data-preview="http://via.placeholder.com/250/00ffff&text=Full Image 1">
            <div class="info hide">
              Price and servings 1
            </div>
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure class="cake-img">
            <img d="img11" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100/0000ff?text=Thumbnail" alt="Naked Wedding Cake with fresh fruit" data-preview="http://via.placeholder.com/250/0000ff&text=Full Image 2">
            <div class="info hide">
              Price and servings 2
            </div>
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure class="cake-img">
            <img id="img12" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100/00ff00?text=Thumbnail" alt="Gold Damask and Pearls" data-preview="http://via.placeholder.com/250/00ff00&text=Full Image 3">
            <div class="info hide">
              <h3>More complicated info</h3>
              <ul>
                <li>Unbox</li>
                <li>Eat</li>
                <li>Watch waistline grow</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
        <img id="preview" src="Resources/img/1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <p id="info">Price and servings here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will make this (wait for it...) a piece of cake ;)

```
$('.cake-img img').mouseover(function(){
    $('#preview').attr('src', this.src)
})
```

You can place this at the end of your page, or in the head, wrapped in a  [document.ready call](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), removing the inline JavaScript you have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple jquery expression that would get this done.

NOTE: this is a broad question, but this will definitly get you pointed in the right direction

```
$(document).on('hover', '.cake-img', function(event) {
    $('.col-md-3').text('sample text here');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is missing `document.` at `getElementById()`

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
<ul class="cake-thumbs">
    <li>
        <figure class="cake-img">
            <img onmouseover="document.getElementById('preview').src=this.src" id="img10" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/city" alt="Pastel Pink Placard and Pearls">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure class="cake-img">
            <img onmouseover="document.getElementById('preview').src=this.src" id="img11" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports" alt="Naked Wedding Cake with fresh fruit">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure class="cake-img">
            <img onmouseover="document.getElementById('preview').src=this.src" id="img12" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/cats" alt="Gold Damask and Pearls">
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
        <img id="preview" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <p id="info">Price and servings here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that I would accomplish what you want. You´d normally have two images a small thumbnail and a larger image. You could put the thumbnail location in the src of your img inside `.cake-image`. Then you would have a link to your full size image, wich would be in the href of `a.image-preview`. This would make your page load faster, since you would originally only load the thumbnails, and load the full image only when needed.

For the text part, I would add a data attribute like `data-description` where i would put the description or other values you want. This then can be extracted using something along the lines of `$("element_selector").data("wha-is-after-hypen").` See the code below.

NOTE: I´m assuming you´re using twitter boostrap and jquery, hence the links at the beggining of the code.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() { //execute this when the document is ready
    $(".image-preview").on("mouseover click", mouseoverHandler); //Bind actions to the mouseover and click events. Why click? because if someone clicks on your link you will be redirected to the image.

    function mouseoverHandler(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default action, in this case click is the trouvlesome one
      $("#preview").prop("src", $(this).attr('href')); // replace the previews src with the href of your link
      $("#info").html($(this).data('description')); //Add the data description to your info element
    };
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <ul class="cake-thumbs">
      <li>
        <a class="image-preview" href="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/7a/18/07/7a18076909f51c90242c4d03e5be012f.jpg" data-description="5">
          <figure class="cake-img">
            <img id="img10" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/7a/18/07/7a18076909f51c90242c4d03e5be012f.jpg" alt="Pastel Pink Placard and Pearls" width="100px">
          </figure>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="image-preview" href="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/cb/e7/99/cbe79953ed564435600981aaffe5593c.jpg" data-description="8">
          <figure class="cake-img">
            <img id="img11" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/cb/e7/99/cbe79953ed564435600981aaffe5593c.jpg" alt="Naked Wedding Cake with fresh fruit" width="100px">
          </figure>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="image-preview" href="https://apis.xogrp.com/media-api/images/b4adc5bb-71b3-f0de-edeb-25f42dc2cf91~sc_320.320" alt="Naked Wedding Cake with fresh fruit" data-description="3">
          <figure class="cake-img">
            <img id="img12" src="https://apis.xogrp.com/media-api/images/b4adc5bb-71b3-f0de-edeb-25f42dc2cf91~sc_320.320" alt="Gold Damask and Pearls" width="100px">
          </figure>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img id="preview" src="" alt="" width="200">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <p id="info">Price and servings here: </p>
  </div>
</div>
```